# netplan equivalent of nmtui?

Tags: networking, netplan

Is there an equivalent of `nmtui` for netplan? I have Googled around and not found an alternative and am trying to avoid having to look it up every time I set up Ubuntu.

Comment: There is no such command, and for good reason: Network Manager is designed for dynamic environments, with new networks and wifi points appearing and disappearing. The current iteration of Netplan is simply not designed for that kind of interactive and dynamic usage. Currently, Netplan is intended for a static/consistent network connection. You can specify *complex* network topologies using Netplan, but not *dynamic*. If you are setting up systems that use netplan, simply copy your netplan yaml.

Comment: There is no such command to configure your netplan interactively. But you can use the `netplan get ...` and `netplan set KEY="VALUE"` commands, read/write the current configuration.